# WCF examples for receiving (consuming) data feeds

Tags: wcf, rss, atom-feed

All the example WCF feed services that I can find are all about generating a feed. What about consuming a feed? Does anyone have any links to examples, or discussions, on a WCF service (.net 4.0 preferably) that can accept an Atom or RSS formatted data feed? I don't need to generate the feed, I need to accept it, validate it, stick the data into a variety of back end  systems (DB, Solr, file system). And by accept, I don't mean I go call some service that returns Atom or RSS, I need to let people Post Atom or RSS to me.

I'm currently looking at having a service that accepts a string, then loads that string into some Syndication objects...but that seems clunky. I'm really amazed that there is no one out there needing to do this, which makes me think I'm doing something hinky.

What about a WCF Data Service (RESTful wcf) that only accepts Add, Update, Delete and not Get. I can find no example of that, and it seems like I'd be breaking some major coding standard if I did it.

Any suggestions, links, ideas, alternate designs would be helpful.
Thanks,
Ken

Re: James' request for more info. I am writing a service that will allow multiple, different, data sets to be posted to it. Similar to GoogleBase. There is a loose definition of the data, but a lot of the individual fields are dynamically defined. Other than a standard format (Atom and RSS) and 1 or 2 required fields, the rest is user defined. What I've done so far is have a Service that accepts an XElement argument. I can then determine at runtime if that XElement is RSS, ATOM, or POX, then I process accordingly. I just wasn't sure if XElement is SOAP and REST and CLR friendly all at once. I was also trying to see if there were more standard ways of doing this. If a service that emits data feeds (this is the primary example available) is like a sun, I'm writing the black hole equivalent. It's a data black hole service to help our partners keep us up to date on any changes to their data that we need to be aware of.

Comment: reversing the normal roles of client and server is pretty odd - can you explain the scenario a bit more?  why would you have people post Atom or RSS instead of something more specific to your scenario?

I'd normally suggest looking at OData and WCF Data Services, but I can't say I really understand enough of your scenario to figure out if that's a good idea or not.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for the answer, i hope not :-)

I was looking for the same thing. Please have a look at the link below. It helped me and it may help someone else also.

http://blog.jschlesinger.net/2009/09/consume-rss-feed-with-wcf-rest-starter.html

Although in the above link the author used program.cs but it is possible to write same code in the WCF service method and expose it.